# R memory not being released after rm(); no objects in environment

Tags: r, memory-management, readr

After running a process to create and write a file, R does not release all the memory:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)

N=100000000

memsize_1_start <- memory.size()

garbage <- tibble(a=runif(N), b=runif(N))

memsize_2_before_write <- memory.size()

readr::write_delim(garbage, "test.dat",col_names = FALSE)

memsize_3_after_write <- memory.size()

rm(garbage)

memsize_4_after_rm <- memory.size()

print(paste0("At start: " ,    memsize_1_start))
print(paste0("Before write: ", memsize_2_before_write))
print(paste0("After write ",   memsize_3_after_write))
print(paste0("After rm ",      memsize_4_after_rm))
```

yields:
[1] "At start: 84.07"

[1] "Before write: 1602.51"

[1] "After write 1628.55"

[1] "After rm 1628.57"

After the rm(), there is no object listed in the environment pane in Rstudio.  My actual use-case  involves reading larger  (30GB) files, in a loop of 10-20 years. A single year's read of the input file results in even more retained memory than demonstrated here and because it is within a loop, I can't restart after each iteration.

How can I recover this memory without a restart?

Comment: Just call `gc()` after `rm(...)`

Comment: You can call `gc()`, but be aware the garbage collector will run automatically if you need more memory so that is unlikely to solve anything if you're running into an `cannot allocate vector of size N` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gc()` within the loop, which will clear some memory after every iteration.